# Computing Error Rate between two columns R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, prediction

I have a matrix as below:

```
Real_Values Predicted_Values
5.5         5.67
6.9         7.01
9.8         9.2
6.5         6.1
10          9.7
1.5         1.0
7.7         7.01
```

I wish to compute the error rate of my model between the predicted and real values and ideally do a plot. I was wondering if R already has a package that neatly does this, so that I will avoid any for loops?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "error rate" ? For example [MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate regression error metrics like the root mean squared error (RMSE) or sum of squared errors (SSE) by hand as pointed out by @nathan-day. Most implementations will automatically do this for you, so you usually don't need to do this by hand.

For the purpose of plotting I'll use a slightly bigger example now, with more samples, as it will be better to understand (the `iris` dataset shipped with R). First we train a linear model to predict the 4th feature from the first 3 features, which already computes some metrics:

```
> model <- train(iris[,1:3], iris[,4], method = 'lm', metric = 'RMSE', trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 10))
> print(model)
Linear Regression 

150 samples
3 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 134, 135, 135, 136, 134, 135, ... 

Resampling results

RMSE  Rsquared  RMSE SD  Rsquared SD
0.19  0.942     0.0399   0.0253
```

The RMSE, SSE, etc. could now be calculated from the predicted and actual values of the target variable by hand too:

```
predicted <- predict(model, iris[,1:3]) # perform the prediction 
actual <- iris[,4]
sqrt(mean((predicted-actual)**2)) # RMSE
sum((predicted-actual)**2) # SSE
```

The slight differences to the results from the model training above results from utilizing a repeated cross-validation (hence the metrics are listed under "resampling results" there).

For the plotting part: regression error can easily be visualized by plotting the predicted against the actual target variable, and/or by plotting the error against the actual value. The perfect fit is represented by the additional line in those plots. This too can easily be achieved with standard tools:

```
plot(predicted~actual)
abline(0,1)

plot(predicted-actual~actual)
abline(0,0)
```

PS: if you are not familiar with regression/classification error measure and robust ML procedures I would strongly recommend spending some time to read up upon those topics - it will likely save you lots of lime later. I personally would recommend [Applied Predictive Modeling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461468485) by Max Kuhn (maintainer of the `caret` package in R) and Kjell Johnson, as it's easy to read and very practical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate Residual Sum of Squares, functions like lm() output this information for you already. Depending on the function you used to model your data accessing the RSS term is a little different.

Based on your data_frame you could easily code the RSS formula in like this

```
datf <- as.data.frame(your_matix)
datf$difsq <- (datf$Real_Values - datf$Predicted_Values)^2
rss <- sum(datf$difsq)
```

Comment: I am quite new to machine learning, so I do not quite know much about the validation methods, but Real_Values are actually the known values, and Predicted_Values are values predicted based on 5-fold-cross-validation, now I want to compare these values to see if my model has performed well, and I don't quite know which method would be best for that purpose, because I have also 2 other tables in the same format from my two other prediction models, so I wish to get some measurement to show which of these models is the best one!

Comment: RSS is typically used for comparing linear models. I don't have a lot of machine learning experience but perhaps this link can help [link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/compare-the-performance-of-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/)